# reverse() on querySnapshot docs not working?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ecmascript-6

I am trying to flip my query snapshot docs but nothing happens:

```
export async function getUserPosts(
  userId,
  getOldPosts = true,
  startAfter,
  limit = MAX_USER_POSTS_TO_RETRIEVE
) {
  ...

  const query = userPostsRef
    .orderBy("date", getOldPosts ? "desc" : "asc")
    .startAfter(startAfter);

  const querySnapshot = await query.limit(limit).get();

  if(!getOldPosts) {
    console.log("=== BEFORE ===");
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((prev) => {
      console.log(prev.data().date.toDate());
    });

    // Flip the docs if we are fetching new posts
    querySnapshot.docs.reverse(); <-----

    console.log("=== AFTER FLIP ===");
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((prev) => {
      console.log(prev.data().date.toDate());
    });
  }

  ...
}
```

When I just call my method like this:

```
getUserPosts("...", false, new Date()); // will execute an orderBy("date", "asc")
```

Console logs the following data:

```
=== BEFORE ===
2021-11-08T20:57:31.382Z   // (oldest)
2021-11-08T20:57:32.816Z
2021-11-08T20:57:36.130Z   // (most recent)

=== AFTER FLIP ===
2021-11-08T20:57:31.382Z   // (oldest)
2021-11-08T20:57:32.816Z
2021-11-08T20:57:36.130Z   // (most recent)
```

As you can see, docs are not flipped... I expect to get

```
=== AFTER FLIP ===
2021-11-08T20:57:36.130Z   // (most recent)
2021-11-08T20:57:32.816Z
2021-11-08T20:57:31.382Z   // (oldest)
```

as the result of the operation, and I don't understand why this is not working if the following code does:

```js
const querySnapshot = {
  docs: [
    {
      data: () => ({ timestamp: 1 })
    },
    {
      data: () => ({ timestamp: 2 })
    }
  ]
}

// Before flipping: [1, 2]
querySnapshot.docs.reverse();

// Expected: [2, 1]
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data().timestamp)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QuerySnapshot.docs` property is calculated, and returns a fresh array each time you call it. Its [implementation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/cdada6c68f9740d13dd6674bcb658e28e68253b6/packages/firestore/src/api/snapshot.ts#L408-L413):

```
/** An array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`. */
get docs(): Array<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>> {
  const result: Array<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>> = [];
  this.forEach(doc => result.push(doc));
  return result;
}
```

So your `reverse()` call reverses an ephemeral array, while your subsequent call to `querySnapshot.docs` then returns a new array in the order from the database.

---

To fix this problem, store a reference to the docs when you first get them from the `QuerySnapshot.docs` and reverse *that*:

```
console.log("=== BEFORE ===");
let docs = querySnapshot.docs;
docs.forEach((prev) => {
  console.log(prev.data().date.toDate());
});

// Flip the docs if we are fetching new posts
docs.reverse(); <-----

console.log("=== AFTER FLIP ===");
docs.forEach((prev) => {
  console.log(prev.data().date.toDate());
});
```